# How to get a probability function from percentiles, average, etc.?

Tags: probability, average, percentile

I have the average, minimum, maximum and p50, p90 and p99 percentiles about the time to takes a website to return an answer. Anyway, I can get other percentiles, like p10, p20, p30, etc.

How can I get a probability function from those values? If this question is too broad, I will appreciate if you can point me on the right direction, so I can research more about it and come back with a more precise question.

Comment: There is an infinite number different PDFs with the same mean, min, max and p percentiles.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork And what about if the shape is similar to a normal distribution skewed left?  Looking at the numbers, there are more samples between p30 and p50, and really low at the extremes. Sorry if I'm not enough precise, but the last time that I saw statistics was in college, like 15 years ago.

Comment: Define "similar to."

Comment: What @DavidG.Stork said is generally and theoretically correct but in the real world you can make a good approximation of the PDF using interpolation(I don't know how to put a link in the comments, but if you google "interpolation" you can read in Wikipedia about it). Because it would be too difficult and time consuming to do this by hand I would suggest that you do this by using specific software(I think that R can do what you are asking for)

Comment: As others have correctly pointed out, it is not theoretically possible. But with some additional domain knowledge you might get closer to estimate a distribution. I'm not very sure if that is what you want. But if you do [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/estimating-a-distribution-based-on-three-percentiles) might be helpful.

Comment: @michailvazaios I was thinking in something like that, in that I have domain knowledge. I will read about it.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Looks like this is what I'm looking for. Let me try first. Thanks!